# Creating a REST service client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I m trying to create a rest service client as a service. Here is my service:

## version 1

```
class MyService
  def self.call(method_name, *args)
    send(method_name, args)
  end
  
  def useful_method
    'id, name'
  end

  # some methods below
end
```

This does not work when I try to invoke methods without any arguments. For example, this:

```
MyService.call(:useful_method)
```

fails because `useful_method` does not expect arguments. Most of my methods have arguments, so this will work in most cases.

I tried this version as well:

## version 2

```
class MyService
  def self.call(*args)
    send(args)
  end
  
  def useful_method
    'id, name'
  end

  # some methods below
end
```

But this does not seem to work for any method with or without arguments.

How can I create something like this that passes `method_name` followed by arguments or no arguments depending on whether the method has arguments?

I think I've seen this [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/AbstractController/Callbacks#process_action-instance_method), but I can't find the source for this.

## Question update

Here is the version 1 error I got :

```
irb(main):001:0> MyService.call(:useful_method)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Here is the version 2 error I got :

```
irb(main):001:0> MyService.call(:useful_method)
TypeError: [:useful_method] is not a symbol nor a string
```

Comment: Can you show the errors you get in both versions?

Comment: @Pablo Sure (pad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
class MyService
  def self.call(*args)
    send(*args)
  end

  class << self
    private 
    def useful_method
      'id, name'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send params to `send` with `send(method_name, *args)

**or**

Defining the Service like this:

```
class MyService
  attr_reader :method_name, :args

  def initialize(options = {})
    # extract attributes
    method_name = options[:method_name] || default_value
    args = options[:args] || []
  end

  def call
    send(method_name, *args)
  end
end
```

and call the service
    `MyService.new(method_name: 'useful_method', args: [staff]).call`

Comment: `*args = nil` is not a valid synthax

Comment: Thanks @Mongoid, The splat doesn't allow defaults, re-edited

Comment: [] (empty) array is still an argument

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call some instance methods from class (static) method. 
You need call `send` to the instance of the class. This should work:

```
class MyService
  def self.call(method_name, *args)
    new.send(method_name, args)
  end

  def useful_method(*args)
    'id, name'
  end

  # some methods below
  end
```

Comment: hi @Muntasim that's not it. I get that same error, thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer with `*args` as the  argument to the `useful_method ` method.

Comment: adding args to the method that does not need it, is a really redundant move